# Dynamically declaring sub-list within a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a list `PairObject` which could have any number of elements.
e.g. `PairObject = ['abc','efg','jkl']`. The elements of list PairObject keeps changing on different condition.

Now I have a list `Price=[[],[],[],[]]` where each sub-list within list Price is associated to each element of list `PairObject` so that the number of sub-lists in list Price is equal to the `len(PairObject)`.

the code is written something like this...

```
PairObject =['abc','efg','jkl']
Price=[[],[],[],[]]
for j in range(0,len(PairObject))
     Price[j].append()
```

Now my question is ... how can I dynamically declare Price, when I don't know the len(PairObject)... which could be 2,3,4 or any number...

Comment: What do you wish to *append*? Give some example input & corresponding expected output. And I suppose you mean you also update `PairObject` dynamically, so you need `Price` to update accordingly?!

Answer (score 2):

If you mean you want

```
len(Price) == len(PairObject)
```

then you can declare `Price` as

```
Price = [[] for _ in range(len(PairObject))]
```